# AngularJS ui-Router - hide $stateParams when navigating between states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, state

So I am using `ui-Router` in my app to pass `$stateParams` and use them in my controllers in more or less clever ways. Point is, some of these `$stateParams` that I pass contain sensitive information, like employee ids. Is there a way to hide them in the url? I saw some answers here about params, but I am not 100% sure that this was the problem those answers were addressing.

So just to be clear, I am talking about information passed in the url like this:

```
.state('detail', {
    url: '/detail/:employeeid/:employeename/:employeeteam',
    templateUrl: 'templates/EmployeeReport.html',
    controller: 'ReportController'
})
```

I want to hide `employeeid`, `employeename` and `employeeteam`.

Thanks!

Comment: Entity ID is likely not a sensitive information. Sensitive information will be employ social security number for example, user password etc. Entity ID is just the ID of the entity in the database.

Comment: Surely if they have this information in the first place, they must have access to it? If the JavaScript knows about it, it must have come from the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use `params`.

Docs - [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

So you can modify your `state` as follows,

```
.state('detail', {
    url: '/detail',
    templateUrl: 'templates/EmployeeReport.html',
    controller: 'ReportController',
    params: { 
        employeeid: null,   // can initialise to default value
        employeename: null, // can initialise to default value
        employeeteam: null  // can initialise to default value
    }
})
```

Your controller code can contain the values for `employeeid`, `employeename`, `employeeteam` as `$scope` variables like,

```
$scope.idVal = 'id';
$scope.nameVal = 'name';
$scope.teamVal = 'team';
```

Your HTML will be as follows,

```
<a ui-sref="detail({
   employeeid:idVal,
   employeename: nameVal,
   employeeteam: teamVal
})"> Details state </a>
```